# Is typescript for `script` command the same as TypeScript maintained by Microsoft? How to print using `ldr`?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Is typescript for `script` command the same as TypeScript maintained by Microsoft? How to print using `ldr` ?

What exactly is typescript in relation to Linux/Ubuntu ?

Searching Google, I find that TypeScript is a superset of Javascript maintained by Microsoft. Is the output of `script` stored using this format?

I see that the output of `script` is binary.

How do I print a typescript file using `ldr` command ?

Answer (score 6):

They are totally unrelated. Microsoft TypeScript is a programming language while under Unix and Linux `typescript` is the default output of the `script` command which is logging everything printed in you terminal session.

Don't be fooled by the binary status reported by `file`, it is due to embedded escape sequences. The better way to display typescript files is using the `less -r` command which preserves formatting/color commands that might be present in the file.

Comment: If this is ASCII, why does my Linux Mint display and icon that symbols a binary file and a file editor like `gedit` cannot display all characters in it ?

Comment: Because it is not just simple ascii, programs can output anything, especially when you use a non English locale.

Comment: How do I print this file output by `script` with the binary (non-ASCII) translated correctly, using `lpr` ?

Comment: The man page says `script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive ses‐
     sion as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).` You can print it directly with `lpr` command, no additional editing necessary

Comment: @jlliagre You wrote:   `Don't be fooled by the binary status reported by file` . Does your `file` command report output of `script` as binary ? Because mine doesn't , only ASCII text

Comment: @serg The output of file applied to a typescript file evolves and depends on what commands where run during the script session. For example, I just ran one and got these status : "empty", "UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF, LF line terminators, with escape sequences, with overstriking" and finally "data".

Comment: But the man page of `script` refers to `typescript` as something defined, not as the name of a file. Indeed, the default name of the output file is `typescript`.

Comment: Typescript is an English word that predates computing science. It originally defines a typed vs handwritten manuscript : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typescript

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `man script`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  script [-a] [-c command] [-e] [-f] [-q] [-t[=file]] [-V] [-h] [file]
> ```

Notice that last `[file]` part. By default, if you simply run `script`  without specifying where to store the file, it will save everything to a file called `typescript`. By contrast, if you run `script somefilename` everything will be saved to `somefilename`.

Now if we run `file` command on `typescript` to determine the file's type, we get this:

```
$ file typescript                                                                                                                                     
typescript: ASCII text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators, with escape sequences, with overstriking
```

As you can see, you've got simple text document there that is *in no way related to Microsoft's TypeScript*. Even more so, since this is a simple text document you should be able to print it with `lpr` command easily.

Word of caution though, if you have output of `ls --color -F` there, you might run into trouble, because `ls` adds special characters to colorize the files based on their type. Thus using simple `\ls` or `dir` is recommended

Comment: Ohh... so typescript refers to the default name of file and not the type/format of file ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen yes, it's just default filename. Not related to java at all

Comment: @Serg TypeScript has no relation to Java too of course!

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy As the filetype is ASCII text, how does script command stores color information?

Comment: @Nikhil It doesn't. It stores  escape sequences, which then are interpreted by terminal and subsequent characters are colorized

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks! Can we make a text editor like vs code interpret the colors? I have a big log file, and I use VS code to search for it.

Comment: @Nikhil Depends on text editor, I suppose. It has to auqpport that in its source